# Hangfire: too many connections opened

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, hangfire

We are using Hangfire in production and turns out that we literally reach the database connections max limitation.

We have about 45 connections for just hangfire which seems a bit too much for just maintaining some long task running jobs.

I am wondering whether there is anything that can be done to change the number of connections, however, I can't find anything in the configuration providing such configuration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try to reduce the number of workers as it is described [here](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/excessive-connection-usage-sqlserver/231):

```
app.UseHangfire(config =>
{
    //tell hangfire to only use 2 workers
    config.UseServer(2);
});
```

Comment: Thanks!
This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: What is the reference of the app.UseHangfire. I am not getting this.

Comment: @AbdusSalamAzad Logically you would have a `Startup` class, in which there would be a method call `Configuration`. This method has one parameter of type `IAppBuilder` and usually is named as `app`. That being said, `app` in the above snippet is the `app` in the `Configuration` method mentioned before. Is now more clear ?

Comment: @Christos, I am asking about UseHangfire not for app. I know 'app' is there, but not finding UseHangfire. I found an alternate UseHangfireServer with workercount =1.

Comment: @AbdusSalamAzad in order to call UseHanglfire, you have to install first the corresponding nuget. I don't know what is the version you want to use, but in any case you need to find iit -> like https://www.nuget.org/packages/HangFirem and then install it. Doing so, it would find the definition of the extension method called UseHangfire.

Comment: @Christos, I am using the latest version of hangfire.On your given link it is showing a 404. Hope, it was for an older version.

Answer (score 5):

Hangfire default takes 20 workers. You can override it on your startup. I used like below:

```
var options = new BackgroundJobServerOptions
            {
               WorkerCount=1    //Hangfire's default worker count is 20, which opens 20 connections simultaneously.
                                // For this we are overriding the default value.
            };

            app.UseHangfireServer(options);
```

Comment: The default number of workers is `Environment.ProcessorCount` (See BackgroundTaskScheduler.cs). In your case it might be 20 but people should check what machine they're deplying to.